# How to prove that $g(x)=x^2$ is integrable on $[2,5]$ using regular partitions?

Tags: integration, riemann-sum, partitions-for-integration

So I've been trying to prove that $g(x)=x^2$ is integrable on the interval $[2,5]$ using regular partitions and the theorem that a function is integrable if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)) = 0.$$

This is what I have so far:

Let

$$g:[2,5]\to \mathbb{R},\quad g(x)=x^2,$$

let $P_n=\{x_0, x_1, x_2,...,x_n\}$ be defined by $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$, $x_k=x_0+k\Delta x$. Set

$$m_k=\inf\{g(x)\,|\,x\in [x_{k-1}, x_k]\}=x_{k-1}^2$$

and

$$M_k=\sup\{g(x)\,|\,x\in [x_{k-1}, x_k]\}=x_k^2.$$

Then

\begin{align*}
L(g, P_n)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{k} m_k(x_k-x_{k-1}) \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{k} x_{k-1}^2 \Delta x \\
&= \Delta x \sum_{n=1}^{k} x_{k-1}^2 \\
&= \Delta x \sum_{n=1}^{k} (x_0+(k-1)\Delta x)^2 \\
&= \Delta x\sum_{n=1}^{k} (x_0^2+2x_0\Delta x (k-1) + ((k-1)\Delta x)^2) \\
&= \Delta x\left(nx_0^2+2nx_0\Delta x \sum_{n=1}^{k}(k-1) + \left(n\Delta x\sum_{n=1}^{k}(k-1)\right)^2\right) \\
&= nx_0^2 \frac{3}{n}+2nx_0\frac{9}{n^2}(0+1+2+...+(n-1)) + n\frac{27}{n^3}(0+1+2+...+(n-1))^2 \\
&=3x_0^2+2x_0\frac{9}{n}\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \frac{27}{n^2}\frac{(n(n-1))^2}{4} \\
&=3x_0^2+x_0{9}(n-1) + \frac{27(n-1)^2}{4} \\
&= 12 + 18(n-1) + \frac{27(n-1)^2}{4}.
\end{align*}

Similarly

$$U(f,P_n)=\sum_{n=1}^{k} M_k(x_k-x_{k-1})=12+18(n+1)+\frac{27(n+1)^2}{4}.$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n)) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(12 + 18(n-1) + \frac{27(n-1)^2}{4}-\left(12+18(n+1)+\frac{27(n+1)^2}{4}\right)\right)$$

And this is where I run into issues because then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(U(f,P_n)-L(f,P_n))$ does not equal zero like it is supposed to. I believe I am running into a computational error somewhere, but I can't seem to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may be overthinking this...here's a hint: a continuous function (e.g. $x^{2}$) that is defined on a compact interval (e.g $[2,5]$) is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Note $L(g,P_n)$ must be smaller than the integral of $g$, so of course it cannot be $12 + 18(n-1) + \frac{27(n-1)^2}{4}$ since this sequence is unbounded.  Therefore, there is an error in your calculation.

Comment: @JWP_HTX I know I can prove it like that, but I'm specfically trying to prove it using partitions and the theory that a function is integrable if the limit of its upper limit minus its lower limit is zero.

Comment: @GEdgar Do you have any idea where this error might be? I've combed over it pretty thoroughly and can't find where I went wrong.

Comment: A way to find errors.  Take a paritcular value of $n$ (as small as possible) where the last line is too big. ($n=3$ will do, and it is particularly nice for the interval $[2,5]$.) Plug that $n$ into one of the lines somewhere in the middle.  If that result is different than your last line, then the error is somewhere in the last half.  Otherwise, somewhere in the first half.  Continue, in each stage approximately dividing the calculation in two halves.  Eventually, you get two adjacent lines with different values.  That is where an error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is that you have confused $n$ for $k$ at various points: when you say $\sum_{n=0}^k$, I think you mean $\sum_{k=0}^n$.

The second error, possibly related, is that you have introduced a factor of $n$ (the sum index) in places where the sum remains e.g. $\sum_{n=1}^k c(k-1)=^?nc\sum_{n=1}^k (k-1)$ for some constant $c$.

The third error is that you have confused $\sum_{i=1}^m i^2=\frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{6}$ for $\sum_{i=1}^m i^3=\frac{(m(m+1))^2}{4}$.

I believe it should read:

$$
\begin{align*}
L(g, P_n)
&=\cdots \\
&= \Delta x\sum_{k=1}^{n} (x_0^2+2x_0\Delta x (k-1) + ((k-1)\Delta x)^2) \\
&= \Delta x\left(nx_0^2+2x_0\Delta x \sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1) + \left(\Delta x\sum_{k=1}^{n}(k-1)\right)^2\right) \\
&= nx_0^2 \frac{3}{n}+2x_0\frac{9}{n^2}(0+1+2+...+(n-1)) + \frac{27}{n^3}(0+1+2+...+(n-1))^2 \\
&=3x_0^2+2x_0\frac{9}{n^2}\frac{n(n-1)}{2} + \frac{27}{n^3}\frac{(n-1)\times n\times 2n}{6} \\
&=3x_0^2+x_0{9}\frac{n-1}{n} + 9\frac{n-1}{n} \\
&= 12 + 27\frac{n-1}{n}.
\end{align*}
$$

Indeed, as $n\to\infty$, $L(g,P_n)\to 39$ and $\int_2^5 x^2 dx=39$.

You will need to calculate $U(g,P_n)$ again with this in mind.